# Can't edit local files due to permission errors once I run docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, composer-php, file-permissions

I run `docker-compose up -d` and then ssh into the container. I can load the site via localhost just fine but when I try to edit the source code on my local it does not let me due to permission errors. This is the ls -la output on container vs local:

**Container:**

[image]

**Local:**

[image]

My dockerfile has the chown command:

[image]

My local user is called **pwm**. I tried running `chown -R pwm:pwm ../app` from host at which point I am able to edit files but then I get laravel permission denied errors. Then I need to run`chown -R www-data:www-data ../app` again to fix it.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

For a development environment, my go-to solution for this is to setup an entrypoint script inside the container that starts as root, changes the user inside the container to match that of the file/directory owner from a volume mount (which will be your user on the host), and then switch to that user to run the app. I've got an example of doing this along with the scripts needed to implement this in your own container in my base image repo: https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base

In there, the fix-perms script does the heavy lifting, including code like the following:

```
# update the uid
if [ -n "$opt_u" ]; then
  OLD_UID=$(getent passwd "${opt_u}" | cut -f3 -d:)
  NEW_UID=$(stat -c "%u" "$1")
  if [ "$OLD_UID" != "$NEW_UID" ]; then
    echo "Changing UID of $opt_u from $OLD_UID to $NEW_UID"
    usermod -u "$NEW_UID" -o "$opt_u"
    if [ -n "$opt_r" ]; then
      find / -xdev -user "$OLD_UID" -exec chown -h "$opt_u" {} \;
    fi
  fi
fi
```

That script is run as root inside the container on startup. The last step of the entrypoints that I run will call something like:

```
exec gosu ${app_user} "$@"
```

which runs the container command as the application user as the new pid 1 executable.